# Running SCP via Perl system() call when running as a service

Tags: services, perl, scp

I created a Debian style service that monitors a database and copies files to a remote machine depending on the data in the database.

When this runs "standalone", the entire process works wonderfully, however, when I run it as a service `/etc/init.d/MonDB start` (which works properly), as a service, scp won't work with error code 256 which I shift to get a code of 1.  According to the docs, this is just a "General Error" and tells me nothing as to why it won't work.

I have been scouring the internet and can't find an answer.

Where I am:

- password prompts are disabled because I have already setup scp to have password-less log in. works.
- I have tried using `-i` to point it to my identity file.
- I have tried to get more data back from the process with -v, but nothing additional comes back.
- I removed strict host checking thinking maybe something there, but I doubted this was an issue.

It runs standalone fine, so the syntax and values are good.

I use the LIST form of `system()`  (perl system() call)  All the entries are in separate elements.  (again, this all works standalone.)

```
system (@PostCMD) == 0 or logEntry ("system @PostCMD failed: $?, $!");
if ($? == -1) {
    logEntry ( "failed to execute: $!\n" );
} elsif ($? & 127) {
    logEntry ( "child died with signal %d, %s coredump\n",
     ($? & 127),  ($? & 128) ? 'with' : 'without' );
} else {
    my $err = $? >> 0;
    logEntry ("child exited with value $err\n");
}
```

My log shows:  (redacted key parts for security.)

```
2015-02-11 22:08:32 system /usr/bin/scp -v -i /home/*****/.ssh/id_rsa 
  -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no /*********file-to-copy******.ext
  xxxxx@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:/xxx/dest/xxx failed: 256, 
2015-02-11 22:08:32 child exited with value 256
```

I don't think this is a Perl problem, it is why won't SCP run when STDIN, STDOUT, and STDERR are clipped off, and also not run from a shell, but as a service.

What does scp need to operate in a service (or from a server process) context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer: setup key-less login for scp and ssh under local root account, to the remote user account being logged into.

Got it!

when I was testing it, I was logged in as my user ID, but when it was running as a service, it was running as root.

I changed the open commands that open STDOUT and STDERR to /dev/null and wrote them to a file.  When I did this, I got the output form -v from scp.  What was happening was, scp was running ssh, but was not passing my identity file -i command, so it was getting access denied, because the effective user id was root, and root had no key on the remote machine for my user account on that machine for ssh to use.

I went through the steps for setting up password-less login, but locally as root, to my remote normal user account.

So, my remote login (non-root) had both keys for my local normal user account and the local root account, after that, it started working.

The process is now working perfectly using scp as a server service.  scp not passing the -i option to ssh is what caused this mess.

Hopefully this helps anyone trying to use scp form cron or other server service type script.

Comment: I considered that as a possibility, but a quick test showed the root user had no problems accessing keys in my home directory when used with `-i`. If `scp` isn't passing on the `-i` flag, perhaps you should file a bug.

Comment: scp does run standalone, I think perhaps the stripped down env that a service or cron runs under (like I was doing) might reveal the issue in detail, I got it working, so, I don't really wana go back and break it to confirm, But it would be a good point to begin a proper test from.